# For a unique item in list1, get the corresponding maximum value in list2 in python

Tags: dictionary, max

I have two lists of elements (list1 and list2) that I generated after parsing a two-columns file. List1 contains items that are repeated different times (i.e a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d) and list2 contains their corresponding values that either are repeated, like in the list1, or are unique.

What I want to do is, for the common items in list1 to get the maximum corresponding number. I am thinking of doing it in python, by initiating a dictionary and, using a condition, to populate it using as a key unique items from list1 and the corresponding maximum value from list2.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you have list1. Can you give an example value of list2? It sounds like you have everything you need in it. Also, your proposed solution sounds right - I think if you sketch it out in pseudocode it will be correct Python.

Comment: so the value of item_i in list1 is, item_i in list2?

Comment: list1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '5', '4', '10', '1', '2']
I want to get a dictionary like: dict = {'a':'3', 'b':'10', 'c':'2'}

Comment: You should expand the question a bit to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine those two lists into one list of pairs using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
# You probably want the values in list2 to be ints
list2 = map(int, list2)
# Combines each item in list1 with the corresponding one in list2
pairs = zip(list1, list2)
```

Then to create a dictionary of the max values, you can just go through those pairs:

```
max_values = {}
for key, value in pairs:
    current_value = max_values.get(key) # None if the key isn't there.
    if current_value is None or current_value < value:
        max_values[key] = value
```